# Sort collection descending but equals values in ascending way

Tags: java

I am trying to sort a collection when I have a not equals `firstValue` and `secondValue` I just return a result of its comparation and It will sort it ascending way, but when these values are equals I wanna sort it by name in ascending way too. Everything works well, but when I have to sort a collection by `firstValue` and `secondValue` in descending way here is I bumped with a problem. When `firstValue` and `secondValue` are equal I wanna still sort it by name in ascending way but using the reverse order it will be sort by Name in descending way.

Here the code for ascending sorting:

```
   prices.setPriceModels(prices.getPriceModels().stream().sorted((o1, o2) -> {
        int compareResult = o1.getPrice().compareTo(o2.getPrice());

        if (compareResult == 0) {
            String firstCompareName = Optional.ofNullable(o1.getName()).orElse(StringUtils.EMPTY);
            String secondCompareName = Optional.ofNullable(o2.getName()).orElse(StringUtils.EMPTY);
            return firstCompareName.compareTo(secondCompareName);
        }
        return compareResult;
    }).collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

The main goal is to sort the whole collection in a descending way and if some values are equals these values should be sort in an ascending way by name. Is it possible to achieve using `reverseOrder()` of stream API? Or what is a better solution for this?

Comment: This is somewhat unrelated, but what is `BigDecimal.valueOf(Double.parseDouble(` meant to do? You already reduce the value to `Double` precision with the `parseDouble` call, I don't see a benefit in wrapping that in a `BigDecimal` after that.

Comment: It was a price in `String` which I converted to `BigDecimal`, I simplified the code.

Comment: Refering to what Joachim said, you should use `new BigDecimal(String)` constructor. No need for weird convertions.

Comment: @JoachimSauer comment makes a lot of sense and it's definitely something you should look into. No, what you're asking is customized sorting and will not be possible without explicit logic.

Comment: Probably the simpliest way to do it would be to negate `compareResult` in the first line.

Comment: What is `firstValue` and `secondValue` in your code? Shorten the question., so that it becomes more clear

Comment: It is the price values

Comment: To be clear, you want to sort the pricemodels in descending order based on price values , and for equal price values, you want to sort the pricemodels in ascending order based on name?

Comment: @boobalan Yes, that's correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this comparator?

```
prices.getPriceModels().stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(PriceModel::getPrice).reversed()  // using PriceModel's Price to sort in descending order
            // for PriceModels with equal Prices, using PriceModel' name to sort in ascending order (with null values of name's treated to be less than any non-null value)
            .thenComparing(PriceModel::getName, Comparator.nullsFirst(Comparator.naturalOrder())))
            .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Comment: That looks cooler that just negotiate a `compareResult`. Thank you